# Converting ZULU DD/HHMM to local HHMM

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been messing with =mod, =text, =right... But I can't seem to find a good function to just display the local time in military format.

I see 21/1800... But I'd like it to sho just 0100 in another cell (adding 7hrs for the local time zone.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try: `=--TEXT(MOD(RIGHT(C15,4)+1800,2400),"00\:00")`